# Использование в программе функций C++

Tags: c++

Помогите, чтобы программа была написана с помощью функции с++

```
#include "iostream"
#include "ctime"

using std::endl;
using std::cout;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int matr[6][6] = { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            matr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            cout << matr[i][j] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        int buf = matr[i][i];
        matr[i][i] = matr[i][5 - i];
        matr[i][5 - i] = buf;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            cout << matr[i][j] << " ";

        cout << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а что сейчас не так? Ну и да, принято заголовки подключать не в кавычках а в `<file>`

Comment: Мелочь, которую стоит знать: не выводи endl без необходимости, это сброс буфера. endl определен ка вывод '\n' и сброс буфера, важно только для синхронизации. Очень многие книги этим злоупотребляют так как в оригинальной STL сброса не было. system("pause"); будет работать только на Windows, но в POSIX есть pause()

Answer (score 2):

Вы имеете в виду замену

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    int buf = matr[i][i];
    matr[i][i] = matr[i][5 - i];
    matr[i][5 - i] = buf;
}
```

кодом

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    std::swap(matr[i][i],matr[i][5 - i]);
}
```

Или что-то иное?

И еще - а что именно вы хотите получить? ну просто чтоб убедиться, что программа делает то, что нужно...

Comment: можно еще for_each добавить и всффякие лябдны. ЧИнтересно, это что, упражнение на то, чтолько фичей студент знает?

Comment: @Swift Да вот и мене непонятно, что требуется...

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вы имеете в виду вот что:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "ctime"

using namespace std;

void setRandValue(int matr[6][6]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
            matr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            cout << matr[i][j] << " ";
        } 
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void swapMatr(int matr[6][6]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        int buf = matr[i][i];
        matr[i][i] = matr[i][5 - i];
        matr[i][5 - i] = buf;
    }
}

void printMatr(int matr[6][6]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            cout << matr[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {

    int matr[6][6] = { 0 };
    setRandValue(matr);

    cout << "\n\n";

    swapMatr(matr);

    printMatr(matr);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Немного гибкий вариант:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int a = 6;
const int b = 6;

typedef array< array< int, a>, b> arr_int;

template<typename t>
void init_array(arr_int& arr,const int& z)
{
    for(auto& i:arr){
        for_each(i.begin(),i.end(),[z](t& s){return s = rand()%z+1;});
    }
}

template<typename t>
void swaps(arr_int& mas)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < a; ++i){
        swap(mas[i][i],mas[i][5-i]);
    }
}

template<typename t>
void print(const arr_int& mas)
{
    for(auto& i:mas){
        for_each(i.cbegin(),i.cend(),[](const t& j){cout<<j<<' ';});
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    arr_int mas;
    init_array<int>(mas,5);
    swaps<int>(mas);
    print<int>(mas);

    return 0;
 }
```